# Find the maximum volume

Tags: geometry

In the sphere of radius 3 is inscribed simple cone. What is the maximum volume of such a cone ?

I have no idea how to find the max volume, I can consider only cone with right angle between the arms then the $V=9 \pi$ but I think it's not the max $V$

Comment: @Henry:  I misread it, as I would have structured the sentence the other way.  You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- express the base radius of the cone in terms of its vertical height (an the radius of the sphere)
- find an expression for the volume of the cone in terms of the vertical height
- find the the vertical height which maximises the volume of the cone
- find the the maximum volume of the cone

Which step is causing you problems or doubts?

Comment: step 1, is the problem. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Draw a picture.  If you slice it with a plane along the cone axis, you have an isosceles triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $3$.  The base is the diameter of the base of the cone, the altitude is the height of the cone.

Comment: If $h$ is the vertical height and $r$ the radius of the cone, and $R$ is the radius of the sphere then $|h-R|^2+r^2=R^2$

Comment: ok, thanks a lot